# Sum of lists in a function

Tags: python, list, function, sum, program-entry-point

I have a question regarding python 'functions' programming.

This is my script:

```
def print_seat(seat):
        for item in seat:
                print "${}".format(item)
        print "-"*15
        total = get_seat_total(seat)
        print "Total: ${}".format(total)

def get_seat_total(seat):
        total = 0
        for dish in seat:
                total += dish
                return total

def main():
        seats = [[19.95], [20.45 + 3.10], [7.00/2, 2.10, 21.45], [7.00/2, 2.10, 14.99]]

        grand_total = 0

        for seat in seats:
                print_seat(seat)

                grand_total += get_seat_total(seat)
                print "\n"
        print "="*15
        print "Grand total: ${}".format(grand_total)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

and this is my script result:

```
$19.95
-----------
Total: $19.95

$23.55
-----------
Total: $23.55

$3.5
$2.1
$21.45
------------
Total: $3.5

$3.5
$2.1
$14.99
------------
Total: $3.5

============
Grand total: $50.5
```

But the result of the script should look like this:

```
$19.95
-----------
Total: $19.95

$23.55
-----------
Total: $23.55

$3.5
$2.1
$21.45
------------
Total: $27.05

$3.5
$2.1
$14.99
------------
Total: $20.59

============
Grand total: $91.14
```

As you can see from above, the total number from the lists are different. I think I wrote everything correctly including the sum of the lists (if I am not mistaken). Could someone pin-point to me what is the problem with the structure of my script? Or I wrote the script wrong?

Comment: Just a sidenote. A better way to sum elements in nested lists is provided by the `itertools.chain` function, e.g. `sum(itertools.chain(*seats))`. This is fast, functional and concise.

Comment: Thanks!!! I will remember that next time I write my script!! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that in your `get_seat_total()` function, you are returning from inside the loop, so it would return the total after adding only the first item. You should only return after the loop has completed, Example -

```
def get_seat_total(seat):
    total = 0
    for dish in seat:
            total += dish
    return total
```

Comment: Thanks man!!! It works like a charm!!! :) Now I know that the 'return' should not be in the loop or else I will only be getting the first item. :) I will bear that in mind!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this Helps,

```
def print_seat(seat):
    for item in seat:
            print "${}".format(item)
    print "-"*15
    total = sum(seat)
    print "Total: ${}".format(total)

def main():
    seats = [[19.95], [20.45 + 3.10], [7.00/2, 2.10, 21.45], [7.00/2, 2.10, 14.99]]

    grand_total = 0

    for seat in seats:
            print_seat(seat)
            grand_total += sum(seat)
            print "\n"
    print "="*15
    print "Grand total: ${}".format(grand_total)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

best,

Comment: or in your script just place the return outside the loop in the function  get_seat_total(seat):  else it picks the first element of the list which is 3.5 in your case.

Comment: Thanks a bunch SuJaY!!! I didn't know I could also ignore the define get_seat_total function and just insert total = sum(seat) to solve the problem!! You all are my saviour!! Thanks again!!

Comment: if it helps you please up vote , coz that can help me. :)